# Gurobi: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tupledict'

Tags: python, gurobi

I have this constraint with big-M parameter and an auxiliary binary variable w:

```
for i in customers:
    for j in customers:
        if i != j:
            mdl.addConstr(y[j] +  z[j] <= y[i] + z[i] - df.demand[j]*(x1[i,j] + x2[i,j])
                          + 100000 * (1 - w), name= 'C8')
```

When I run the code, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tupledict'
```

w is defined as follows:

```
w = mdl.addVars(0,1,vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='w')
```

I couldn't figure out what is the problem? Is it a problem in defining w?
Thank you

Comment: can you provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`w` is `tupledict` as it was defined using [mdl.addVars](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_addvars.html).

As `w` is a single variable you need to define it using [mdl.addVar](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_addvar.html) instead:

```py
w = mdl.addVar(0,1,vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='w')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Indeed, it is a single variable :)